# Переадресация в nginx

Tags: nginx

В nginx добавил правило

```
location = /index.php {
    if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
        rewrite ^ https://$host? permanent;#301 redirect
    }
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/fastcgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Но это правило отсекает index.php только на главной странице.
Как добавить правило для всех index.php а не только на главной странице?

Тело всего файла:

```html
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  300;
    server_tokens off;
    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
        client_max_body_size 128m;
        server {
                server_name localhost;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
        location @fallback {
                error_log /dev/null crit;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                access_log off ;
        }
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
# disabled by ISPmanager

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhosts/brixo/site.com.conf:
server {
  server_name site.com www.site.com;
  charset UTF-8;
  access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
  return 301 https://site.com$request_uri;
  listen 185.149.243.194:80;
  # ht(passwd|access)
  location ~* /\.ht  { deny all; }
}

server {
  server_name site.com www.site.com;
  ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/brixo/www_site_com_2023_01_21.crt";
  ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/brixo/www_site_com_2023_01_21.key";
  ssl_ciphers EECDH:+AES256:-3DES:RSA+AES:!NULL:!RC4;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam4096.pem;
  charset UTF-8;
  index index.php index.html;
  disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
  include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/site.com/*.conf;
  access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.com.error.log notice;
  ssi on;
  set $root_path /var/www/brixo/data/www/site.com;
  set $catalog_path /public/catalog;
  root $root_path;
  listen 185.149.243.194:443 ssl;
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 5;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
#   rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;


  location /robots.txt {
    root /var/www/brixo/data/www/site.com;
  }

#   location = /index.php {
#     if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
#         rewrite ^ https://$host? permanent;#301 redirect
#     }
#     fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/fastcgi.sock;
#     fastcgi_index  index.php;
#     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#     include        fastcgi_params;
#   }

  location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
      try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }

    location ~* ^(.*)/index.php$ {
      if ($uri = /index.php) {
          rewrite ^ https://$host? permanent;#301 redirect
      }
    }

    location = /index.php {
      if ($uri = /index.php) {
          rewrite ^ https://$host? permanent;#301 redirect
      }
    }

    location ~ ^/catalog/files/(.*) {
      try_files /storage/files/$1 =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/upload/(.*)$ {
      add_header X-uri-upload $uri;
      try_files /public$uri @fallback;
    }

    location ~ ^/catalog/?(.*)$ {
      add_header X-catalog $uri always;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }

    location ~ ^/bitrix/?(.*)$ {

      add_header X-bitrix $uri always;
      try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }

#    location ~* ^.+\.(bmp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff|ttf|eot|woff2|json|xml|ico|icon|webmanifest)$ {
    location ~* ^.+\.(bmp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff|ttf|eot|woff2|xml|ico|icon|webmanifest)$ {
      add_header X-uri-ff $uri;
      try_files $uri $catalog_path$uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }

#    location ~ ^/catalog/api/(.*) {
#      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32500;
#      proxy_set_header Host $host;
#      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
#    }

#    location ~ ^/catalog/(.*)$ {
#      try_files $catalog_path/$1 $catalog_path/index.html =404;
#    }

#    location /favicons/ {
#      try_files $uri @fallback;
#    }

    location / {
      add_header X-root $uri always;
#      try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:32080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }
}

  location @fallback {
    add_header X-uri-fallback $uri;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    access_log off;
  }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/blacklist-nginx.conf:
        location @blacklist {
        proxy_redirect off ;
        proxy_pass https://185.117.153.83:1500;
        rewrite (.*) /mancgi/ddos break;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X_ISP_FIREWALLSEC 124afcdc9287c555c4507f68dffc67fd1d704d8b92b78c2911c82d285664b668afb24441390a96fd5a16653912cd37303d84bbcf3b47f84c0f2574658a2ace39dc127
a151c1112762778b03945e769826b2451a66c49f27b6f66e1f990af326cc1ac81debd9354e40b041e50eb87d256ac23fc186dee93dc5474d5e4230750e5;
        }

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/disabled.conf:
location /disabled/ {
        alias /usr/local/mgr5/www/disabled/;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/letsencrypt.conf:
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/;
}
# configuration file /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/phpmyadmin-nginx.conf:
location /phpmyadmin {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        index index.php;
}
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
        error_page 404 @apache;
}
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.www-data.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        error_page 502 = @apache;
        error_page 404 = @apache;
}
location @apache {
        error_log /dev/null crit;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/setup {
        deny all;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы редиректить на URL без index.php на конце добавьте следующий блок:

```
location ~* ^(.*)/index.php$ {
    return 301 https://$host$1;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал добавить и в server {) и в location / {} , безрезультатно, редиректа на страницу без index.php не идет

Comment: покажтите конфиг и сообщите какой url тестируете, что ожидаете и что получаете. Напомню, что после изменения конфига нужно перезагружать сервис

Comment: Тестирую на примере ссылки     `site.ru/business/franchises/euro-auto/index.php` В сам вопрос добавил тело файла с настройками nginx, на выходе хочу получить ссылку без index.php, вместо этого получаю ту же ссылку и пустую страницу

Comment: http или https ? Ожидаете получить 301 редирект на https://site.ru/business/franchises/euro-auto/ ? Что получаете ?

Comment: https, получаю пустую страницу, с ответом 200, ожидаю получить 301 редирект на site.ru/business/franchises/euro-auto

Comment: приложенные вами конфиги не обрабатывают запрос с указанием хоста site.ru т.к. у них другой server_name.

Comment: nginx -T выведет полный актуальный конфиг

Comment: Поменял файл на актуальный

Comment: уберите этот блок ```location ~* ^(.*)/index.php$``` и предложенный мной location поставьте перед этим ```location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$``` и не забудьте перечитать конфиг командой nginx -s reload

Comment: `
  location / {
    location ~* ^(.*)/index.php$ {
      return 301 https://$host$1;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
      try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }`   Добавил, перезагрузил, сайт упал с ошибкой    `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Редирект есть? Как проверяете? Сайт может падать по разным причинам. До падения доберемся тоже.

Comment: Да, редирект происходит, возвращает 301, и отсекает index.php, проверка в режиме разработчкика в браузере.

Comment: т.к. вопрос касается переадрессации, то его нужно закрыть и создать новый вопрос про 500-ку

Comment: Спасибо, создал новый вопрос))